# styled-components: parent styles has more priority then child

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

[image](https://image.ibb.co/inNesF/2017_08_10_12_47_17_screenshot.png)

```
export const LogOutButton = styled.button`
  display: inline-block;
  ....
`;
export default styled(ThemedApp)`
  ....
  button {
    ....
    display: flex;
    ....
  }
`;
```

as you see, `Logout button`(has class `gBuhXv`) has `display: flex`, instead of `inline-block`, because priority of parent(`ThemedApp`, `.jCe...`) is bigger

The rule that leads to this is `p.column { text-align: right; }` can be overwritten by `body p.column { text-align: left; }`, cause it more specific

Its right behavior, but not that I expect, how to make priority of Logout button bigger?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that

```
const globalStyles = styled.div`
p {
  color: ${props => props.theme.somecolor};
}
a {
  color: ${props => props.theme.somecolor};
}`
```

isn't the right usage of styled-components.

Instead, I have to define components and extend them:

```
const P = styled.p`
  color: ${props => props.theme.somecolor};
`
const A = styled.A`
  color: ${props => props.theme.somecolor};
`
const CustomA = A.extend`
  color: mycolor;
`
```

Comment: If you can post [identical answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45628743/styled-components-style-in-theme-is-overriding-component-style/45630704#45630704) to two of your questions, then that suggests the questions are duplicates of one another. Otherwise, you should be tailoring your answers to the question that is actually being asked.

Comment: Yes, they are dublicates