# styled-components: style in theme is overriding component style

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

[Reproduction](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KrF0eSCVu0HNEvTPi9u)

Expected: `palevioletred` color of Title, and red of TitleWithoutColor (theme styles triggered)

Got: red everywhere

Why: The rule that leads to this is like: `p.column { text-align: right; }` can be overwritten by `body p.column { text-align: left; }`, cause it more specific

Question: how to write themes so that styles of components would have bigger priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found solution, problem was that

```
const globalStyles = styled.div`
p {
  color: ${props => props.theme.somecolor};
}
a {
  color: ${props => props.theme.somecolor};
}`
```

isnt right usage of styled-components, instead I have to define components and extend them

```
const P = styled.p`
  color: ${props => props.theme.somecolor};
`
const A = styled.A`
  color: ${props => props.theme.somecolor};
`
const CustomA = A.extend`
  color: mycolor;
`
```

Comment: This solution increase amount of code in your JS and affects overall performance of the app because more classes need to be generated.

The correct solution would be to use more specific styles for child either by `> p {}` or `&& { p {} }`

Answer (score 0):

Reactjs

```
<div id = "random_component"></div>
```

Css

```
#random_component {
    color: #0000 !important ;
}
```

Sometimes reactjs styling is not recognized as more specific than the framework you may be using. This comes from the fact that most frameworks have their styling coded in Css. To fix this, use Css to override current framework by defining a `className` or an `id`. Also, you can add the "`!important`" command to make sure all other level of specificity are overruled.

Comment: Seems like hack, and I dont want to use css (on nextjs its hard)

Comment: From my experience themes are all written in css or similar languages (sometimes sass). If you want to override them, you will have to pass through css. If you find another solution using reactjs though, I'm all ears!

Comment: 2017, styled-components, no more classes